# C++ Compilation error against GNU's Multi-precision library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gnu

I get the following error when compiling [this third-party library](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~behle/azove.html) (called **azove 2.0**) which relies on the [GNU Multi-precision library](http://gmplib.org/):

```
> make
g++ -Wall -O3 -DFIX_NUMBER_OF_SIGMDDNODE_SONS -DUSE_TIMER -I. -c conBDD.cpp -o conBDD.o
In file included from conBDDnode.hpp:27,
                 from conBDD.hpp:25,
                 from conBDD.cpp:22:
/usr/include/gmpxx.h: In destructor ‘__gmp_alloc_cstring::~__gmp_alloc_cstring()’:
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:2096: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
conBDD.cpp: In member function ‘void conBDD::build()’:
conBDD.cpp:61: error: ‘numeric_limits’ was not declared in this scope
conBDD.cpp:61: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
conBDD.cpp:61: error: expected `;' before ‘int’
conBDD.cpp:68: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
conBDD.cpp:68: error: expected `;' before ‘int’
make: *** [conBDD.o] Error 1
```

I have tried adding either and both of the following lines

```
#include <cstdlib> 

using std::strlen;
```

to `conBDD.cpp`, but the error persists.

I can't tell if this is an error comes from GNU's Multi-precision library or from Azove. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `std::strlen` is defined in `<cstring>`. Also, you put only one `:` in the `using`. It seems strange to me that GMP has this kind of error, but you could try to `#include <cstring>` too.

Comment: Also, the error with `numeric_limits` seems to do with relying on having used `using namespace std;` in the code of Azove. Maybe a bug in that library?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by apportioning blame. Create an empty cpp file, say test.cpp, in your project and include only the offending gmpxx.h file. If you can compile test cpp, GMP is off the hook. Then try including only the offending azove header. If you can compile the azove header in an otherwise empty file, azove is off the hook and something you are including/defining is interfering with them. Once you have narrowed down the source of the problem you should find it easier to fix.